# How do you make a UISegmentedControl follow dynamic type?

Tags: accessibility, uisegmentedcontrol

I have started applying dynamic type and preferred fonts to my app. The only part of the view controller that doesn't conform is a pair of segmented controllers that stay stubbornly small when the labels etc are all expanding with the larger text slider in settings.

Answer (score 5):

As of October 2018, it seems like `UILabel` is the only class that has dynamic updation behaviors for accessibility built-in, in the form of the `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` boolean flag. If you set this flag to `true` on a `UILabel`, and set a dynamic type font for the label, the label will dynamically resize itself (and its own frame) based on the current content size settings. This also works for things like `UIButton`, which internally use `UILabel` for displaying text.

For controls like `UISegmentedControl`, unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a boolean flag that can be flipped on or off. Here's how I implement it:

In your `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib` or after you've setup your view, you want to register for the content size change notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector:#selector(userChangedTextSize(notification:)),
                                               name: UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification,
                                               object: nil)
```

Now in the `userChangedTextSize` method, you want to reset the font on the segmented control:

```
 @objc private func userChangedTextSize(notification: Notification) {
    // Replace textStyle with whatever textStyle you want for your segmented control
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([
                .font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
                ], for: UIControl.State())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In UIKit 14 the only ones components which support "Dynamic type" feature are

- UILabel
- UITextField
- UITextview

Also UILabels which are a part of the UINavigationBar, UIBarButtonItem and UITableViewCell use the Dynamic type out of the box.

UIKit Components which still lacks the feature are:

- UIButton
- UISegementedControl

Comment: You can set a button because you have access to the label by doing `button.titleLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`